# Firestore transactions showing unexpected behaviour when used in cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am writing an app that features an inventory in which users can reserve products. I want to ensure that 2 users cannot simultaneously reserve a product at the same time, for this, I intend on using transactions. When using transactions from the Firebase SDK, everything works as intended, but I am getting unexpected behavior when using transactions from a callable cloud function. To simulate the use case where 2 users happen to reserve the same product, I use setTimeout in my cloud function to halt the function for 3 seconds. I am launching this function from 2 different clients with different user contexts.

```
export const reserveProduct = functions.https.onCall(async (data,context) => {

 function testTimeout(){

     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
         setTimeout(()=> {
           
           return resolve(true)
        },3000)
       })

 }

if(!context.auth){
    return {
        error: `You must be logged in to reserve products`
    }
}else{


    const productRef = admin.firestore().collection('products').doc(data.productID)
    const userRef = admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(context.auth.uid)

    return admin.firestore().runTransaction((transaction) => {
        return transaction.get(productRef).then(async(doc) => {
            if(doc.get('status') == 'reserved'){
                throw "Document already reserved!"
            }else{
                console.log("Product not reserved, reserving now!")
            }

            await testTimeout()

            transaction.update(productRef, {status: 'reserved'});
            transaction.update(userRef, {reserved: admin.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(data.productID)})

            
        })
    }).then(() => {
        console.log("Transaction Successfully committed !")
    }).catch((error) => {
      
        throw "Transaction failed, product already reserved"
    })

    


}
```

After running this function call from 2 different clients simultaneously, The function call from my first client returns successfully as expected, but only after roughly 35s (which is way too long for the simplicity of the transaction). However, the second function call times out without returning any value. I have not seen any documentation explicitly stating the use of transactions in callable cloud functions, nor should it be affected when used within the emulator.

I am expecting to simply get a return value for whichever function call is able to modify the data first, and catch the error from the function which has retried and validated the reserved state.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are not managing the life cycle of your cloud function correctly: as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#sending_back_the_result) you need to return data that can be JSON encoded wen all the asynchronous work is complete. For example, in the last `then()` block, do `return {result: "Transaction Successfully committed"}`. This error most probably explains why you have to wait 35s and may solve your transaction problem (I haven't tested).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Renaud, I added that return statement and behavior remains the same, whichever function call is able to modify the data first needs to wait 31s for a result (And it is always 31 seconds, never more, never less, which seems a little suspicious ), and then the second function call, of course, receives a timeout error after 60 seconds. It is worth noting that when I wrap my transaction's update within a timeout, instead of awaiting a promise, The function throws a "Cannot modify a writeBatch that has been comitted" Error, instead of halting for 31s or timing out.

Answer (score 0):

One major difference between the two places is in the way the SDKs used handle transactions:

- The client-side SDKs use an optimistic compare-and-set approach for transactions, meaning that they pass the values you read in the transaction with the data you're writing. The server then only writes the new data if the documents you read haven't been updated.
- The server-side SDKs (used in your Cloud Function) use a more traditional pessimistic approach for transactions, and place a lock on each document that you read in the transaction.

You can read more about [database contention in the SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention#data_contention_in_the_server_client_libraries) in the documentation.

While I'm not exactly certain how this is affecting your code, I suspect it *is* relevant to the difference in behavior you're seeing between the client-side and server-side implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank, I did read up on the documentation and came to notice that transactions were indeed handled differently when written on the cloud vs on the client, however, it seems like the formatting for transactions remains indifferent, at least as far as I can see from the documentation.  If I remove the timeout, the transaction does behave regularly, but that leaves me with no concrete way of testing if the transaction is actually doing something when multiple clients are attempting to modify the data simultaneously. Any suggestions ?